# ODBC connection successful, basic query generating cant connect error 10061

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, odbc

We are migrating from MySQL to MSSQL. I created a ODBC connection and tested the connection parameters, which was successful (via `ODBC Data Sources Administrator`). Also, on a separate note, I am able to connect to MySQL workbench and query the MySQL database successfully.

When I try to run the following command in SQL Server to confirm the ODBC connection is set up correctly:

```
SELECT * INTO testMySQL.dbo.shoutbox
FROM openquery(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM phonebook.contacts')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL".
```

One thing to note, MySQL is running on port 3307 and SQL server is running on port 3306.

Also, here is the ODBC connection query I used to establish the connection:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
@server = N'MYSQL',
@srvproduct=N'MYSQL',
@provider= N'MSDASQL',
@provstr=N'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=127.0.0.1;
         DATABASE=phonebook; USER=root; PASSWORD=123456; OPTION=3'
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: 32bit  - 64bit configuration problem?

Comment: Thanks @bummi, Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Supposing you are on 64bit there two places to define an ODBC connection odbcad32 from SysWOW64 or System32. Maybe you configured the wrong one?

Comment: Thanks @bummi, I appreciate the suggestion. However, even after confirming I configured the correct one, I am getting the same error.